# Can I redirect to same domain but different currency?

Tags: magento2, redirect, nginx

I have request like this:

> - redirect domainB to domainA --> USD
> - redirect domainC to domainA --> EUR

Can I set currency like that? thanks advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can apply following solution:

1. Create multilple store view with different languaes and do settings in the .htaccess file as per domain and store view, Sample code below :

   ServerName          domainB.com
       ServerAlias         "www.domainB.com"
       DocumentRoot        /path/to/your/magento2/
       SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE "EUR"
       SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE "store"

   ServerName          domainA.com
       DocumentRoot        /path/to/your/magento2/
       SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE "USD"
       SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE "store"

Comment: Thanks for your times @saphaljha. Maybe you is mistake. I mean after setup for two subdomain redirect to same domainA but set diffecence currency.